# Problems in logging in to the admin section of my website

Tags: php, mysql

I downloaded the Admin Login Panel from Apphp.com.
It worked fine on localhost.

Then I created a database in the Parallel Plesk Server [Where my website is hosted], assigned a user to it, imported the sql file and created the tables.

Then I changed the config.inc.php settings from:

```
     function Config()
     {              
        $this->host     = "localhost";  
        $this->user     = "root";
        $this->password = "";
        $this->database = "testdb";
     }
```

to

```
    function Config() 
    {
      $this->host     = "pemysql01.365techsupport.com:3306";  
      $this->user     = "user123";
      $this->password = "password";
      $this->database = "testdb";               
    }
```

As I said already that the code is working fine in localhost, but when I upload the database and other files to the server, I cannot login with my username and password which is 'test' & 'test'. It says, wrong username or password. The same code is working fine on localhost.

Is there anything else that I have to do, or can anyone suggest me a simple php based login panel source code from any site.

Comment: Are you check your DB connection ok?

Comment: what is the error you're getting?!

Answer (score 0):

Trying from here:

```
$ mysql -h pemysql01.365techsupport.com -u test -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test'@'xx.xx.xx.xx' (using password: YES)
```

You probably has the same problem from your php machine (i.e. you need to grant it access)